# Maximal ideal in a polynomial ring over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

the problem is to show the ideal generated by $x^2-2$ and $5$ in a polynomial ring over $\mathbb Z$ is maximal. i tried to show the quotient ring of the ideal is a field. it turned out to be something like a quadratic integer(of modulo 5)ring. but this is strange to me.

i wonder if there is a better way to solve this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track:
$$
\mathbb Z[x]/\langle 5, x^2-2 \rangle
\cong
(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[x]/\langle x^2-2 \rangle
$$

It all boils down to proving that $x^2-2$ is irreducible mod $5$, that is, that $2$ is not a square mod $5$, which is immediate.

Here is a concrete elementary way to prove that $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[x]/\langle x^2-2 \rangle$ is a field.

$(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[x]/\langle x^2-2 \rangle \cong (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[u]$, with $u^2=2$. The elements of this ring are of the form $au+b$, with $a,b \in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.

When $a=0$, all elements $b$ have inverses, except of course when $b=0$.

When $a\ne 0$, then $a$ has an inverse mod $5$, say $A$. Then $au+b=a(u+Ab)$ and so it suffices to prove that all elements of the form $u+b$ have inverses. This is easy:

$b=0: u \cdot 3u = 3u^2 = 6 = 1$

$b=\pm1: (u\pm1)(u\pm4) = u^2\pm 5u +4 = 6 = 1$

$b=\pm2: (u\pm2)(2u\pm1) = 2u^2\pm 5u +2 = 6 = 1$

Comment: oh thank you so much. but i haven't learned the irreducibility yet. could you explain why the quotient ring is a field without the concept of the irreducibility?